# Matlab - can't display manually set axes

Tags: matlab, panel, uicontrol, axes

I create a figure and a panel of uicontrols. When I run the program, the panel overlays the default axes( or plot area if that is more appropriate). So, I want to have the panel at a certain position and the axes( or plot area) set at a separate position. I've read Matlab help and tried many variations of set, get, CurrentAxes, axis methods. Still I can't figure out. The basic code until now, is

```
mytitle = 'Kinematic Control of a Redudant Robotic System';
simfig = figure( 'menubar', 'none', 'position', [ 140 140 600 600], 'Name', mytitle, 'NumberTitle', 'off');
ax = axes( 'Parent', simfig, 'Units', pixels, 'Position', [ 150 150 300 300], 'XLim', [ 0 10], 'YLim', [ 0 8]);
panbut  = uipanel( simfig, 'Units', pixels, 'position', [20 45 143 150], 'Title', 'Simulation Buttons');
%buttons
up      = uicontrol( panbut, 'style', 'pushbutton', 'string', 'up',   'position', [ 50 90 40 40], 'callback', @up_button_press);
down    = uicontrol( panbut, 'style', 'pushbutton', 'string', 'down', 'position', [ 50 10 40 40], 'callback', @down_button_press); 
right   = uicontrol( panbut, 'style', 'pushbutton', 'string', 'right','position', [ 90 50 40 40], 'callback', @right_button_press); 
left    = uicontrol( panbut, 'style', 'pushbutton', 'string', 'left', 'position', [ 10 50 40 40], 'callback', @left_button_press);
```

What do I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you position your plots using the `position` property, results can be quite inaccurate, because the space for labels and ticklabels add to the space you define in `position`.

In order to avoid overlap you can set the `OuterPosition` property of the `axes`:

```
mytitle = 'Kinematic Control of a Redudant Robotic System';
simfig = figure( 'menubar', 'none', 'position', [ 140 140 600 600],...
    'Name', mytitle, 'NumberTitle', 'off');
ax = axes( 'Parent', simfig, 'Units', 'pixels','outerPosition', [ 150 150 300 300], ...
    'XLim', [ 0 10], 'YLim', [ 0 8]);
panbut  = uipanel( simfig, 'Units', 'pixels', 'position',...
    [20 45 143 150], 'Title', 'Simulation Buttons');
%buttons
up      = uicontrol( panbut, 'style', 'pushbutton',...
    'string', 'up',   'position', [ 50 90 40 40],...
    'callback', @up_button_press);
down    = uicontrol( panbut, 'style', 'pushbutton',...
    'string', 'down', 'position', [ 50 10 40 40], ...
    'callback', @down_button_press);
right   = uicontrol( panbut, 'style', 'pushbutton',...
    'string', 'right','position', [ 90 50 40 40], ...
    'callback', @right_button_press);
left    = uicontrol( panbut, 'style', 'pushbutton',...
    'string', 'left', 'position', [ 10 50 40 40],...
    'callback', @left_button_press);
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The outerposition property, solved my problem.

Comment: @user1397055 - if this solved your problem, please hit the checkmark to formally accept it.